# Create a safe-threaded client library to connect to an external API

Tags: c#, multithreading, dotnet-httpclient

Sorry for the name of my post but I am going to try to explain my problem.

I am building a client library to request an external API and I try to figure out how to make the methods of my library safe-threaded.

Basically the main class of my library looks like this :

```
public class MyCompanyApiClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MyCompanyApiClient(string baseUrl)
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient() {BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl)};
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<MyClassB> PostData(int id, MyClassA dataToPost)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"objects/{id}");
        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToPost), Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json");

        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClassB>(stringContent);
    }

    public async Task<MyClassA > GetById(int id)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

I'd like to ensure that any instance members of my client class are safe-threaded.

For the moment I plan to wrap the code inside each method into a `Task.Run`:

```
public async Task<MyClassB> PostData(int id, MyClassA dataToPost)
{
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"objects/{id}");
        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToPost), Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json");

        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        var stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClassB>(stringContent);
    });
}
```

By the way I don't even know if it is going to ensure this method to be safe-threaded.

Any help aprreciated ^^

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a threading issue at all. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: This class will be used into an azure webjob that process a high volume of message from an eventhub and I would like to ensure that I am not going to have any issue about safe-threading but may be I am overthinking the problem.

Comment: @Thomas It's *thread-safe*, not *safe-thread*

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer thanks, I'll edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread-safe doesn't mean *multi-threading*.

It means that some code is aware that it'll be used in multi-threaded cases, and they won't get corrupted, won't produce deadlocks and other threading-related issues.

Sometimes there's code that it's thread-safe *per se*, while sometimes you need to use thread-synchronization approaches like monitors, mutexes, reset events, semaphores and others, to protect critical code sections from being executed by one, two or *n* threads at once in order to avoid, again, deadlocks, corruptions and, basically, unexpected behaviors.

In your case, it seems like you consider *thread-safe* launching your `PostData`as a thread in the thread pool. This is a bad choice, you don't need a new thread for this.

Comment: Thanks Matias for this explanation. I am going to close the question ^^

Comment: @Thomas What do you mean by closing the question? :D If my answer was useful, you can mark it as your solution.

Comment: Yea sure but I can't do it right now, i need to wait ^^

Comment: @Thomas No problem, I was just showing you how SO works. Since you said "I'm going to close the question", closing means not accepting more answers and this requires close votes on que question itself :)